# How can I solve nested RDD in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, recommendation-engine

```
//For your request, I updated my code for value 'combinations'.
//val list =  rdd looks like this -> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Array[Int])] 
 val combinations = list.mapValues(_.toSeq.combinations(2).toArray.map{ case Seq(x,y) => (x,y)}).map(_._2)

val combinations :Array[Array[(Int, Int)]] = Array(Array((1953,1307), (1953,527), (1953,1272), (1953,1387), (1953,318)),Array(( ...))...)


val simOnly = combinations.foreach{ x => 
    x.map{ case(item_1, item_2) =>
        val itemFactor_1 = modelMLlib.productFeatures.lookup(item_1).head
        val itemFactor_2 = modelMLlib.productFeatures.lookup(item_2).head
        val itemVector_1 = new DoubleMatrix(itemFactor_1)
        val itemVector_2 = new DoubleMatrix(itemFactor_2)
        val sim = cosineSimilarity(itemVector_1,itemVector_2)
        sim
    }
}
```

This is my code that calculates the cosine similarity between items.

but the nested RDD doesn't support in apache spark

How can I solve this properly?

```
  And my interpreter show this
 //org.apache.spark.SparkException: This RDD lacks a SparkContext. It could happen in the following cases:
  (1) RDD transformations and actions are NOT invoked by the driver, but inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
 (2) When a Spark Streaming job recovers from checkpoint, this exception will be hit if a reference to an RDD not defined by the streaming job is used in DStream operations. For more information, See SPARK-13758.
```

Comment: can you update code with rdd one

Comment: You call `foreach` over an array, then `map` over those elements to some unknown function call. Where is the RDD object?

Comment: @cricket_007 I updated it, is this enough?

Comment: @AkashSethi I updated it and I do not know if it's what you want.

Comment: what i want to see is transformation on RDD not on array

Comment: @AkashSethi Sorry I'm very beginner in spark, So what you want to see is the transformation on rdds . But I don't know how to show you